# Can $X_4 \times S^1$, $X_4 \times I^1$, or $X_4 \times \mathbb{R}^1$ be a triangulable, PL or DIFF manifold, if $X_4$ is a non-triangulable manifold?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, 4-manifolds, triangulations, topological-manifolds

Question: If $X_4$ is a non-triangulable topological (TOP) manifold,

1. can $X_4 \times S^1$, $X_4 \times I^1$, or $X_4 \times \mathbb{R}^1$ be a triangulable manifold?
2. can $X_4 \times S^1$, $X_4 \times I^1$, or $X_4 \times \mathbb{R}^1$ be a PL manifold?
3. can $X_4 \times S^1$, $X_4 \times I^1$, or $X_4 \times \mathbb{R}^1$ be a smooth DIFF manifold?

Note that we have smooth (DIFF) ⊂ PL ⊂ triangulable ⊂ TOP.

(If $X_4$ spin or non-spin manifold makes a difference for the answer, then we should discuss the differences.) The $I^1$ means a 1-dimensional finite internal.

---

Let $X_4$ be a $4$-manifold which is *NOT* a triangulable manifold but only a topological manifold.

---

### Other warm-up info:

- If $X_4$ is the non-triangulable Freedman's E8 topological manifold, then $X_{4+}=X_4\times T^$ is triangulable, but not piecewise linear (PL).
- Any orientable 5-manifold is triangulable.

This question is a more specific version of [the previous one](https://mathoverflow.net/q/385189/27004) focusing on $d=4$ only.

Comment: I guess that the other question may not be answered, that is why I asked a specific simplified question. Thank you! (also I ask the PL, which we have: smooth $\subset$ PL $\subset$ triangulable.

Comment: It is more likely that this question can have an immediate answer by an expert. (The other question - I am not sure who can answer.)

Comment: This question is not simplified. On the contrary, it is one of the difficult cases of the other question. You have already got answers to the other one.